# Unity List not showing in Inspector

Tags: list, unity-game-engine, variables

I am making a health UI and got everything working but for some reason the list is no longer showing up in the UI. Here is the function (which works supposedly)

```
public void HeartUI()
{
    //hearts[i].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>.sprite;
    for (int i = 0; i < hearts.Length; i++)
    {
        if(i < health)
        {
            hearts[i].image = fullHeart.texture;
        }
        else
        {
            hearts[i].image = EmptyHeart.texture;
        }

        if(i < maxhealth)
        {
            hearts[i].SetEnabled(true);
        }
        else 
        {
            hearts[i].SetEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

and here are the variables:

```
public Image[] hearts;
public Sprite fullHeart;
public Sprite EmptyHeart;
```

Again, the list hearts is not showing up in the editor and it is giving me the error: `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object playerMovement.HeartUI` (at the line where the for loop starts)

Any help will be appreciated as this is for a school project and I really need this to work

Answer (score 0):

Give it a starting array nr. It showns 0 items. If this is not the problem then you have som typo inside your script and pls allocate the nr of images.